# How to catch server errors in Nuxt.js so it doesn't crash page render? (Vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo

**Context**

This question is related to my other question, [How to handle apollo client errors crashing page render in Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029623/how-to-handle-apollo-client-errors-crashing-page-render-in-nuxt)
, but I'll try to keep this isolated since I'd like this question focused only on Nuxt (minus apollo). However, I decided to ask this separate since I'm looking for an entirely different response/solution.

**The problem**

I'm currently maintaining a production Nuxt/Vue app that is using the `@nuxt/apollo` module to make GraphQL requests.

The problem, is that every now and then, the GraphQL server we rely on goes down and returns an HTML error page, which crashes the Apollo client. But because we're loading Apollo as a nuxt module, it crashes the page render pipeline as well. Giving us a generic server error page that looks like this;

[image: page error]

> Server error
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

And the following stack trace:

```
 ERROR  Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0                                                            08:11:04

  at new ApolloError (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1588:34
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2008:15
  at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2006:26
  at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2004:20)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1483:29
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

However, none of this stack trace allows us to see where nuxt is throwing the error, so we can handle it.

**What we tried**

We've exhausted all our options looking into this issue for the past couple of weeks. We first tried to solve it by handling the error directly at Apollo level using all 3 apollo library abstractions's error handling solutions:

- `@nuxt/apollo` module
- `vue-apollo`
- `apollo-client`

If you'd like to read up more on that (even though its kind of irrelevant to this question), you can read more on my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66029623/how-to-handle-apollo-client-errors-crashing-page-render-in-nuxt)

However, right now I'd prefer to know if there's a way to somehow handle these page render errors either by:

- Making the errors fail silently, so the page still renders as normal
- Allowing us to redirect to another page.

Since the apollo nuxt module we are using currently isn't working for that, I'd like to know if Nuxt supports some kind of way to handle errors.

It didn't help much that Nuxt's documentation is pretty limited when it comes to error handling. At best, it has information regarding the error pages and how to redirect to the error pages using `context.error`. But it doesn't have a dedicated page on how to catch common errors. I have a feeling Nuxt hooks could be the answer, but documentation on them is hard to navigate and also sparse.

The most complete information source I found on nuxt error handling was this article, [Error handling in NuxtJS](https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20200904-ErrorHandlingInNuxtjs.html), of which nothing suggested worked for us.

**Summary**

Our nuxt app is crashing when the `@nuxt/apollo` nuxt module we are using crashes. We'd like to know if there's some kind of standard nuxt way of catching it, or if the only solution possible is just migrating our entire app to not use `@nuxt/apollo` module and use the ES6 promise syntax and load `apollo-client` manually into the app as a standalone library that's not deeply integrated into the nuxt lifecycle.

Comment: It looks like you already found a solution for your problem and to answer your question there is no default way to handle error in Nuxt it all depends on where the error accurse (https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20200904-ErrorHandlingInNuxtjs.html). The easiest way to solve the problem is where it accurse what is in Apollo module. And it looks like you solve it in your last version on Git

Comment: Actually, I still have the error @VictorPerez, I "patched" it by using the apollo link error middleware, but this causes a "vnodes mismatch" nuxt issue that ends up with a white screen in prod mode. So not really a solution either I'm afraid

Comment: I actually already went over that article a few times before asking this question, but that only gave me ways to log the error to the console or report it to Sentry. Not so much in terms of catching the error so it fails silently, unless I missed something? If you know of a way to handle this error silently without relying on the apollo link error middleware, that would solve all our issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** I myself think that the problem lies somewhere in the Vue Apollo plugin or Nuxt Apollo module and how errors are handled there. I would think you can handle the error directly at the Apollo module but that is not possible in SSR.

You have to keep in mind that you probably need another solution for both CSR as well as for SSR.

In short, what happens is that the `renderRoute` fails and because of this SSR ends up in the default `errorMiddleware` of Nuxt.

**1:** Calling Apollo query directly, this gives you full control over the error handling for that page and will work for both CSR and for SSR

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    if (!this.books.length) {
      // client side
      this.fetchBooks()
    }
  },

  serverPrefetch() {
    this.fetchBooks()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchBooks() {
      this.$apollo
        .query({
          query: gql`
            query books {
              books {
                title
                author
                test
              }
            }
          `,
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e)
        })
        .then((data) => {
          /// set books
        })
    },
  },
}
```

**2:** Add a `errorMiddleware` hook and handle the error there. This only works for SSR. Important to understand is that rendering failed so you have to redirect or render another page.

```js
//nuxt.config.js
 hooks: {
    render: {
      errorMiddleware(app) {
        app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
          res.writeHead(307, {
            Location: '/network-error',
          })
          res.end()
        })
      },
    },
  },
```

**3:** Return false in the `error` method of Apollo, This only works for CSR

```js
export default {
  apollo: {
    books: {
      query() {
        return gql`
          query books {
            books {
              title
              author
              test
            }
          }
        `
      },
      error() {
        return false
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: yup, we already plan to switch to this approach. Sorry I didn't mention this before. However, the codebase is quite large and migrating every single vue apollo smart query to this will take a long time. So we are hoping there's some way to handle these errors without a full refactor. I agree with you though, its likely something to do with the nuxt apollo module.

Comment: @sgarcia.dev please see my edit version, with more detailed explanation

Comment: Thank you for elaborating @victor-perez, step #2 of your update proved very helpful. Does that mean that the most we can do with SSR errors, is catch them with the error hook, and use `res.writeHead` to redirect to a new route? Asking in case there's a way to get access to the Nuxt context somehow, but I imagine that's probably not possible on SSR errors, correct?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent pages from being crashed, you need to handle errors and isolate them so they won't affect the rendering of other components. This can be achieved with the error handling concept of `ErrorBoundary`. You can create a common component to reuse the `ErrorBoundary` logic. There are several other benefits of this approach.

- Helps to keep components free from error handling logic
- Allows us to use declarative component composition instead of relying on imperative try/catch
- We can be as granular as we want with it — wrap individual components or entire application pieces.

Here is the example of how to create an error boundary.

```
export default {
  name: 'ErrorBoundary',
  data: () => ({
    error: false
  }),
  errorCaptured (err, vm, info) {
    this.error = true
  },
  render (h) {
    return this.error ? h('p', 'Something went wrong') : this.$slots.default[0]
  }
}
```

Now, you can wrap any component to the error boundary and isolate the error as given,

```
<error-boundary>
  <counter />
</error-boundary>
```

#### Caveats of `ErrorBoundary` component

There are some caveats when utilizing the `errorCaptured` hook. Currently, errors are only captured in:

- render functions
- watcher callbacks
- lifecycle hooks
- component event handlers

Comment: Hey Kiran! I tried your Error Boundary solution by creating a new `<ErrorBoundary>` wrapper component and adding your code there, and wrapping a component that caused this Apollo Client error, but the error still crashed page render. Just letting you know